# Global variable is not passed

Tags: php, global-variables

I am trying to use a declared array in a function but that produces exactly nothing and I do not understand why.

```
<?php
$pages = array("missing-demos", "missing-downloads", "remove-demos");

function kz_check_adminmenu($action)
{
    global $pages;

    print_r($pages);
}
?>
```

Well the function is called as it is showing on the menu (I am using a CMS). However, echo-ing the method does print the desired output. I still do not understand why it doesn't show where it's executed.

Comment: You're not `calling` your function. Place this above your `?>` `kz_check_adminmenu($action);`

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually calling the function anywhere? :

```
<?php
$pages = array("missing-demos", "missing-downloads", "remove-demos");

function kz_check_adminmenu($action)
{
    global $pages;

    print_r($pages);
}

kz_check_adminmenu('test');
?>
```

This will ouput your array

Answer (score 0):

You're not `calling` your function.

Place this `kz_check_adminmenu($action);` above your `?>` tag.

```
<?php
 $pages = array("missing-demos", "missing-downloads", "remove-demos");

function kz_check_adminmenu($action)
{
    global $pages;

    print_r($pages);
}

kz_check_adminmenu($action);
?>
```

Comment: because my comment was posted first (evidently the solution) and I made it an answer. @JustinIurman See the timestamps. It wasn't posted in the form of a question *"Are you actually calling the function anywhere?"*

Comment: What i see is a comment & a post after first user's answer. But i don't even care about that, it's only useless

Comment: I didn't see the answer posted while I was indenting the code for my answer. @JustinIurman